# package resolution failed xcode could not be resolved

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

[image]

I am encountering a problem while installing facebook ios sdk

Clean derived data, reset package caches, resolve package version, restart Xcode - not work

Comment: Another thing to try is to remove the package from the project and then add it back

Comment: I have managed to make it work only a few times, most other times it fails. I tried disabling my VPN connection, and that does not make a difference either. I am trying to reset package cache, resolve package versions, delete and re-add, and even restart my machine. It keeps failing to resolve.

Comment: I encounter same issue, following the [swift-package-manager](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk#swift-package-manager).
have trying to implement resolve package version, clean project, restart Xcode, still can't install.